# Do some side quests become unavailable later on in the game? (Dragon Quest IX)

Tags: dragon-quest-9

Are there any side quests that become unavailable after a certain point in Dragon Quest IX or can I come back any time and do them all (for example after finishing the main storyline)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nintendo shut off the wifi for this game (along with all other DS titles) As of May 2014. Because of this, you are no longer able to download any of the DLC quests, making all of these unavailable at this time. If you had them downloaded from before this time, you should still be able to complete them.

Otherwise, no. At any time (assuming you have the means to get there), you can go back to any area of the game and finish side quests there.

Comment: Yeah I meant the sidequests in the main game. What do you mean when you say "assuming you have the means to get there"? Can't you use the Zoom spell anytime?

Comment: I have not played the game for quite a while, so I do not remember if there are any points in the game where you lose access to your vehicles. You may not be able to zoom in a certain spot, etc. It just covers the times in the game where you technically cannot get to a side quest, but none of them are ever closed.

Comment: Do you remember if you can travel anywhere after the end of the game?

Comment: Yes you can. Many of the grottos and quests are going to end up being harder than the end of the game, and expect you to have done so.